# Identification of pole

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

I would like to know whether the following statement is true or not

> If $f$ is an analytic function satisfied $|f(z)|\to\infty$ when $z\to z_0$, then $f$ is a pole at $z=z_0$

I would say the statement is false.

By a theorem in my textbook, for $z=z_0$ be a pole of $f$, it requires $$lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=\infty$$

We know that $lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=L$ implies $lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=|L|$ (the proof is skipped), but the reverse may not be true. So $lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=\infty$ may not give $lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=\infty$. That is, we cannot conclude that it is a pole.

Can I say in this way?

Comment: What is your definition of pole? (In many books your quoted text is taken as the definition of a pole.)

Comment: @mrf There is a theorem in the book says that if $z_0$ is a pole of $f$, then $lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=\infty$ (but not $lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=\infty$)

Comment: Ok, but in the context of complex numbers and complex analysis, $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = \infty$ and  $\lim_{z\to z_0} |f(z)| = \infty$ means the same thing. There is only "one infinity" in the (extended) complex plane.

Comment: Omg...
Thanks :(